# Are all humans in Futurama actually aliens?

Tags: futurama

In the season seven episode *The Thief of Baghead*, Bender is going through various lenses with his camera. Among those he tries out is [the "They Live" lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live), which shows everyone as the aliens seen in the linked film.

So does this lens show everyone as they truly are, or would it be more along the lines of an FX lens like those we apply in apps these days like Instagram?

Comment: Futurama is just referencing the awesome movie from the 80s: [They Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live).  Where some citizens appeared as aliens when viewed with special sunglasses developed by a secret resistance group.  In the movie, only some humans were aliens, 75% were still just regular humans.  (Also advertising would appear as signs telling people to "Obey", "Conform", "Reproduce", etc.)

Comment: Oh I'm aware. Which is why I'm curious as to their alien status. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's pretty obviously a novelty lens along the lines of Instagram.

Remember, they did a genetic profile on Fry when he was unfrozen, and matched him to a descendant.  His DNA is human, the Professor's DNA is human, and even the mutants are still (mostly) human.

Zoidberg isn't human, but then he's never pretended to be.

Comment: Accepting this for lack of other answers, but I'm still suspicious. Just because he's been matched to a descendant doesn't preclude him from being an alien!

Comment: Being from the year 2000 might make him a better candidate than the 'modern' humans though.